# Can't restore a dump backup file for Postgres using pg_restore

Tags: postgresql, psql

I generated a dump backup file for my Postgres 9.3.4 using this:

```
pg_dump table_name -U myusername -h localhost -O > backup.dump
```

Now I'm trying to backup the old database using:

```
pg_restore -U myusername -n public -d table_name  backup.dump
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
pg_restore: [archiver] input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql.
```

Please note that the file is not plain sql file since I generated it using pg_dump.

I used the follwoing command:

```
psql perchwell -U myusername -f backup.dump -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1
```

and start receiving the following error:

```
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
psql:backup.dump:16: ERROR:  schema "propertydir" already exists
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default output format of pg_dump is actually plaintext sql script. So use psql for import or redump with the `-Fc` flag.

Comment: Thanks Eelke, I'm using **psql -U myusername -d db_name -1 -f backup.dump** and I keep getting: "invalid command \N". Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: use pg_dump, not psql

Comment: @EkiEqbal Please edit your question to show the full output. Run psql with `-v ON_ERROR_STOP=1` as well.

Comment: You get a schema already exists because the database is not clean. First create a new database and import into that.

Comment: marceljg He's trying to import it--not what pg_dump is for.

Answer (score 0):

Your bug: pg_restore: [archiver] input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql

Bug indicate use psql command to import database.

```
cat your-dump-pg-file.dump | psql -d your-database
```

This way, you can easily restore file

In additionally if you set character set UTF-8, will make better import too.